# Is there a way to map just part of a column to a variable?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have two date columns in my table, `START_DATE` and `END_DATE`. I'm using an Oracle XE 11g db, and have learned that I can select just a portion of the date (such as the month). I'd like my objects to have a `startMonth`, `endMonth`, `startHour`, and `endHour`. I know how to select these things from the two columns in my database ([as this article explains](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html)), but I can't figure out how to map them to the variables.

A bit of further explanation, the start and end hours represent daily availability during the period of time from the start month to the end month. I'm using Eclipse Kepler, Spring IDE 3.5, and Hibernate 4.3.5 if any of that makes any difference.

This table won't be changing once it's populated, so I won't be saving anything from the object to the db, just reading from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a [Formula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e3147):

> Sometimes, you want the Database to do some computation for you rather than in the JVM, you might also create some kind of virtual column. You can use a SQL fragment (aka formula) instead of mapping a property into a column. This kind of property is read only (its value is calculated by your formula fragment).

```
@Formula("obj_length * obj_height * obj_width")
public long getObjectVolume()
```

That said, be very careful: a given date in a given timezone might not be in the same month as the same date in another timezone. Using the database to figure that out is a strategy that can't work if you deal with multiple timezones.

Also, be aware that if you change the value of the date in your Java code, and then ask for the value of the month, you'll not get the new date's month, but the value of the month as it was loaded initially. Maybe you should simply create a getter method that computes the month based on the current date every time it's called. This, however, won't let you create queries based on the month.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! It looks like you can put a Select statement inside the formula as well as a conventional formula/calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it manually, you can just add the fields in the query:

```
select TO_CHAR(START_DATE,<your pattern for hour>) as START_HOUR,
       TO_CHAR(START_DATE,<your pattern for month>) as START_MONTH,
       ...
```

and then map them easily, as if your table had the 4 fields you need.

Another option is having a setter and multiple getters, one for each part of the field you need:

```
setStartDate(date) {
    this.startDate=date
}
getStartMonth() {
    return this.startDate.get(Date.MONTH) + 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I haven't used queries for mapping anything else because I'm using Hibernate. Everything else maps directly to a column.

Comment: Ok, then check @JBNizet answer, it's the same but using Hibernate features. I guess it will fit better if you are using JPA and an entity manager.